# 'android' resize a view inside a fragment

Tags: android, resize, fragment, viewgroup

I'm struggling with programmatically resize a view inside a fragment, this Fragment is also in a
FragmentStatePagerAdapter to cycling with another two views.

I have declared and instantiated the views as I always did

then I have this method to apply resizing on each view:

```
private void dimensioniEmargini(View view, int width, int height, int marginLeft, int marginTop, int marginBotton, int marginRight) {

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parametri;
        parametri = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        parametri.height = height;
        parametri.width = width;
        parametri.leftMargin = marginLeft;
        parametri.topMargin = marginTop;
        parametri.bottomMargin = marginBotton;
        parametri.rightMargin = marginRight;
        view.setLayoutParams(parametri);

    }
```

My problem is: if I call it from onCreateView it works perfectly but, if I call from another method (inside the same class), like the one below (where I give values just to try it out)

```
public void aggiornaDimensioni(String _query) {

        dimensioniEmargini(barraCorretto, 45, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    }
```

I obtain a null pointer exception:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.view.View.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference

I need to resize from a method because it is called from parent activity and is meant to change size according to database querying.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.view.View.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference
```

This means that you're calling `getLayoutParams()` on a null `View` object. So here:

```
parametri = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
```

`view` is null. So whatever you pass in during `onCreateView` is fine, but `barraCorretto` is null when you call it from that other function.

Remember a `Fragment` has to have gone through a layout (through `onCreateView`) before you can do `getView()`, and `Fragment`s can be destroyed and recreated.

Comment: Thank you! Is it the same inside an activity? I tried too but again, null pointer exception!
So how can i have a view that resizes dynamically and more times?

Comment: How are you getting that ``View`` you're passing in? Just check it's not null before you call ``dimensioniEmargini`` with it - if you don't have the ``view``, then there's nothing to resize!

Comment: OMG! I was forgotten to initialize!
I would never notice without you, thank you so much!!! ))